# How to copy "c" 2Darray into "c++" 2Darray?

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array

This file `maze.txt`:

```
12,20
++++++++++++++++++++
+                  +
+ + + ++++ + +++++ +
+ + +++ ++ + ++ ++ +
+ +   +    + ++    +
+ +++ ++++++ +++++++
+  s+     ++ +g+   +
+ +++++++ ++ + + + +
+ +       ++ +   + +
++++++++++++ +++++ +
+                  +
++++++++++++++++++++
```

I would like to read into C array (because I know C I/O better then C++ IO), and then copy it into `std::vector<std::vector<char>>`:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <vector>


int main(){
    FILE *fp = fopen("maze.txt", "r");
    int rows, cols;
    fscanf(fp, "%d,%d\n", &rows, &cols);
    char(*buf)[cols] = (char(*)[cols])malloc(sizeof *buf * rows);

    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
        {
            char c = fgetc(fp);
            if (c == '\n')
            {
                c = fgetc(fp);
            }
            buf[i][j] = c;
        }
    }

    std::vector<std::vector<char>> dvec(rows);
    for(int i = 0; i<rows; i++){
        dvec[i].reserve(cols);
        std::copy(buf[i], sizeof(buf[i]), std::back_inserter(dvec[i]));
    }
}
```

I am getting template deduction error:

```
no matching function for call to ‘copy(char [cols], long unsigned int, std::back_insert_iterator<std::vector<char> >)’
```

So how to realize the copy?

Comment: *"I would like to read into C array (because I know C I/O better then C++ IO),"* -- but you are not reading into a C array. You are reading into a `char`. Transferring that character to a C array, then transferring that C array to a C++ vector is wasteful and not supported by your reasoning. If you add one line, change another, and move the declaration of `dvec` earlier, you could directly transfer the character to the vector and reduce both code size and execution time. Win-win. Unfortunately, that is not what you asked about...

Answer (score 0):

`char(*buf)[cols]` is valid C, but invalid C++. You really can't mix languages like this. C and C++ have a common past, but evolved separately,

As a result, there's no C++ `std::copy` that can handle your C VLA.

Comment: How to do then `memcpy`, which could copy the C VLA into std::vector?

Comment: @milanHrabos: that's a C function and can't handle the C++ `std::back_inserter`.